# Angular: Set default dates for p-calendar

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-calendar

I like to set default Dates for p-calendar PrimeNG component, how do I do that in Angular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ngModel` for that.

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="value"></p-calendar>
```

and set your specific date for `value` property. For instance, if you want to set a date one month before today :

```
this.value = new Date();
this.value.setMonth(this.value.getMonth() - 1);
```

See [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/MYHdOo5cPXR7zTC91ceA?p=preview)

Comment: This works thanks, but I want to set date to 30 days ago, how do I do that, given that the current date is this?

Comment: @Kenadet you're welcome. Please approve this answer if it helped you

Comment: @Antikhippe, i want to do the same but in my case i've to show a range in p-calendar. Can you please help.